# Get value from nested tuple in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json reponse from an api, I need get the 'askPrice' value from:

```
dict_items(
    [
        ('SPY', 
            {
                 'assetType': 'ETF', 
                 'assetMainType': 'EQUITY', 
                 'cusip': '78462F103', 
                 'assetSubType': 'ETF', 
                 'symbol': 'SPY', 
                 'description': 'SPDR S&P 500', 
                 'bidPrice': 435.31, 
                 'bidSize': 2100, 
                 'bidId': 'T', 
                 'askPrice': 435.33, 
                 'askSize': 200, 
                 'askId': 'P', 
                 'lastPrice': 435.32, 
                 'lastSize': 0, 
                 ... , 
                 'delayed': True, 
                 'realtimeEntitled': False
             }
         )
     ]
 )
```

My code is:

```
quote = c.get_quotes("SPY")
resp = quote.json().items()
print(pd.json_normalize(resp['SPY']['AskPrice'],level=2))
```

But python interpreter show error:

> TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

I appologize for this simple question.

Comment: Remove the `.items()` part, or `resp = dict(quote.json().items())`

Comment: What is the source of this financial symbol? Are you using their API?

Comment: a `dict_items` object is a _view object_. You can iterate on view objects, check for membership and get their length, but you cannot do anything else on them - in particular they are not subscriptable, hence the error you get

Comment: Many thanks to all. Thanks to aswer of Cyttorak the loop has already worked. Im using non-official python tda-api.